# Running Production WAMP

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, windows-server-2008-r2

I am building a new Windows Server 2008 R2 install to host my Joomla! 1.6 website. What are best practices of hosting a WAMP production server? What should I do for partition? A drive for logs, a drive for the OS and a drive for data? What would be the most ideal and secure setup?

Comment: Has anyone ever heard of the Uniform Server? They say it is a stack designed for production. Any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best practices are not to use it. It's best to pick tools native to your platform. If you want to run an *AMP stack, do it on Linux/Unix and install/configure the components individually, don't use a preconfigured package that's aimed at development.

The default configuration for WAMP/LAMP is extremely insecure, because it's meant to give a quick turnkey dev environment. It's not a production solution. If you really care about security, you'll install each component separately and follow the best practices for security for each product individually.

Comment: I wish. I want to run it on CentOS but its not my call.

Comment: Using a native platform is only a small part of my answer. You should still install and configure each individual component separately, even if you *must* use Windows, it's just less-than-ideal to run it on Windows.

Comment: So you're saying I should just install each component individually on Windows? That sounds feasible. Do you recommend any current/up-to-date documentation on each component?

Comment: They're *all* well documented. apache.org, mysql.com, php.net, etc.